# Scenario for transferring a user account from one person to another

Tags: administration, user-management, user-admin

If Phil is promoted from a Sales Associate to Senior Sales Exec, and the new sales associate is appointed to take Phil's responsibilities.
What are the appropriate steps to transfer Phil's account to the new associate?

[A]. Overwrite Phil's User Profile with the new associates information and create a new profile for Phil.

[B]. Create a new profile for Phil as well as new associate. Deactivate Phil's profile with Sales Associate role and transfer all the accounts, opportunities and leads to the new associate.

[C]. Associate the new role to Phil's existing profile and Transfer all the accounts, opportunities and leads to the new associate.

[D]. None of the above

I have found the answer to [B] from many resources.

Can anyone help me please with the analogy behind this answer?

Answer (score 1):

The standard Salesforce answer to this will always be:
*Create a new user for the new Associate. Phil is assumably taking a new role (or profile)*.
You then use the mass transfer tool in setup to transfer all of Phil's (Leads, Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, etc.) to the new associate. There are some nuances to this approach so best to go through this documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_transfer.htm&language=en_US

So yes [B] is probably the best approach!